# How to compose objects that are purely side effects?

Tags: design-patterns, dependency-injection, functional-programming, object-oriented-analysis

Consider the following example:

1. There is a class A which is purely a side-effect producing object (e.g. Logging analytics data let's say)
2. This class A is heavy. i.e. You don't want to have more than 1 of it in a single process. The methods in this class are also thread-safe.
3. Class B does some business logic. Similarly Class C also exists which is used by Class B and C also does some business logic.
4. Both B and C want to use A and perform those side-effects.

Question: What is the right way of composing these 3 classes?

Option-1:

```c
class B {
    public B(A a) {
        c = new C(a)
    }

    public Foo calcXX() {
        // do something useful using C
        a.doSideEffect(..)
        return foo;
    }
}

class C {
    public C(A a) { ... }

    public Bar calcBar() {
        a.doSideEffect(...)
        return bar;
    }
}
```

Cons of Option-1:

1. If class A is not a business object, but instead is more auxiliary like Analytics class or a Configuration class, then, Option-1 seems to pollute the constructor signatures unnecessarily.

Option-2:

```c
class B {
    public B() {
        a = A.getInstance()
    }

    public Foo calcXX() {
        // do something useful using C
        a.doSideEffect(..)
        return foo;
    }
}

class C {
    public C() { a = A.getInstance() }

    public Bar calcBar() {
        a.doSideEffect(...)
        return bar;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just looking at the code without having read your post, I'd favour option 1, as it doesn't seem to require the singleton.

Comment: These are not equivalent.  Option 2 includes the code to find the instance of A that you're using.  Option 1 requires that calling code find that instance.  Option 1 is likely to have a copy of A getting passed through numerous construction chains, so I think option 2 is generally better; however, best yet would be to convert the functions of A into static functions, so you wouldn't have to worry about any A object at all.

Comment: I'd favour option 1. You're not polluting the constructor signatures "unnecessarily"; both classes *do* need to be told about an `A`, and the most straightforward *and* flexible way to do that is for it to be passed in from the outside. Hiding this dependency on `A` might make your constructor signatures *appear* less complex, but it doesn't make the overall architecture/design less complex, and it does make it less obvious.

Answer (score 3):

None of the options suggested here are particularly good.

1. The first option (slightly) violates [Nikola Malovic's 4th Law of IoC](http://blog.vuscode.com/malovicn/archive/2009/10/16/inversion-of-control-single-responsibility-principle-and-nikola-s-laws-of-dependency-injection.aspx) that [Injection Constructors should be simple](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple). The specific offender is `B`'s constructor, which creates a new `C`. If `B` needs an instance of `C`, it should declare that in its constructor.
2. The first option utilizes the Singleton pattern, which *can* be appropriate, but hides the clients' dependencies, and tends to make it harder to reuse the consuming classes (and thereby also makes them harder to unit test).

A better option would be this:

```
class B {
    public B(A a, C c) { }
    public Foo calcXX() {
        // do something useful using C
        a.doSideEffect(..)
        return foo;
    }
}

class C {
    public C(A a) { ... }
    public Bar calcBar() {
        a.doSideEffect(...)
        return bar;
    }
}
```

The fact that `C` also uses `A` is irrelevant to `B`.

You can now compose instances of `B` and `C` like this:

```
a = new A()
c = new C(a)
b = new B(a, c)
```

Notice that the same instance of `A` is being used by both `b` and `c`.

For more information about efficient graph composition, see http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/04/Composeobjectgraphswithconfidence